# Variable with float stays zero in C

Tags: c

When i use `scanf` to assign `euro` a user input it will result in zero. I can´t figure out why it is behaving like this.

```
float euro;
int main(void){

  printf("Ange euro: ");
  scanf("%d", &euro);
  printf("%d", euro);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you're doing is undefined. `%d` is the format specifier for integers. Use `%f`

Comment: Use `%f` for accepting float values.

Comment: Either your complier warnings are not fully enabled or you are using a weak compiler.  A warning _should_ have occurred saving you time.  Consider enabling all warnings or get a new compiler.

Comment: I'm using codeblocks ide with GNU GCC compiler. Is that a weak one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `%f` specifier for float values, `%d` is used for integer.

```
#include<stdio.h>

float euro;
int main(void){

  printf("Ange euro: ");
  scanf("%f", &euro);
  printf("%.2f\n", euro);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the proper format specifier. Change format specifier `%d` to `%f`

```
  scanf("%f", &euro);
  printf("%f", euro);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you declared euro as a float variable, you need to have the appropriate format specifier. For floats, it's `%f`.

Here's a nice list of format specifiers for `printf` and `scanf` statements: 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/